# How to pass command line arguments in truffle exec

Tags: truffle

How to pass command line arguments to `<file.js>` when using truffle exec? --

```
truffle exec <file.js> <arg1> <arg2> ...
```

Comment: Your are on node, so you can use process.argv or any other library that parses the command line, you might have to require('process') like any other javascript file.

Comment: @Ismael you are right, process.argv works. If you bother to put up an answer I'll accept it.